# Micro service alert configuration using Prometheus

Tags: microservices, alert, prometheus, grafana, azure-aks

I need some help in monitoring Micro services which are running on AKS cluster using existing Prometheus which is running on a different node.

How can we detect and setup alerts for a number of scenarios around pods like
out of memory issues and pods getting restarted? I have checked few articles on internet but most of them are addressing the issue in which both micro services and Prometheus is running on same AKS cluster. But in my case, Prometheus is already configured on different node and we are using node_exporter and black_box_exporter to monitor other servers. I do not want to disturb the existing setup of Prometheus.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Sharmila

Comment: welcome to SO. if you already have prometheus, node_exporter, and black_box_exporter it seems that you already have the necessary metrics. Now you have to set up alert manager (https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/alertmanager/) in order to configure new alerts.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I dont have node_exporter or blackbox_exporter installed on AKS cluster yet. So, you want me to install node_exporter on the AKS cluster on which my pods are running for them to monitor them?